# Playing DRM songs

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have an audio tag like this:

```
<audio id="myAudio" msaudiocategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"></audio>
```

to which I set the src property to

```
URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
```

and then call

```
myAudio.play();
```

This works well for my personal mp3's, but songs downloaded through the Xbox Music Pass, which I assume are under DRM, simply do not play. There's no audio and the 'timeupdate' event never fires. I don't see any exception or message in the Output window.

I tried playing those same songs with VLC, and I get no audio while the progress bar advances normally.

Is it possible to play those songs outside of the official apps?

Edit: and if it isn't, can we detect if a music file is DRM'ed so as to prevent its usage in our apps?

Comment: To answer part of my question, it is possible to filter out DRM songs by specifying "protected:=No" in the search filter query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are DRM'd files, so they need the DRM keys, etc etc.

Since those are private to the application, it's not possible to play that DRM'd content outside of those applications.